# include_once not working correctly

Tags: php, include, iis-6

I am trying to make a page that returns a file if the page is being requested by a user, and returns a api response if requested by code. It works fine but google chrome (and ie) render the user page as if it was:

```
<head></head>
<body><title>BLAH</title>
<h1>Bloo bloo blah</h1></body>
```

Even though view source returns:

```
<head><title>BLAH</title></head>
<body><h1>Bloo bloo blah</h1></body>
```

but when I go to the page that is being included, it displays improperly.

PHP code:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['mode']) {
    echo 'server response';
}
else {
    include_once('main.php');
}
?>
```

main.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>BLAH</title></head>
<body><h1>Bloo bloo blah</h1></body> 
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
I am using IIS 6.1 with PHP 5.3.5 running on a Windows 7 computer.

Comment: please provide more details, what is this `main.php` does?

Comment: We need more [input](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbkbU32X5dI)

Comment: @ajreal - main.php basically just does nothing- **at the moment**

Comment: you should `focus on the actual HTML returned`, `not what browser rendered`

Comment: oh wierd, the source is correct, but the rendering still displays a bit of whitespace at the top of the file...

Comment: Try removing whitespaces below the tags

Comment: removed all whitespace... doesnt work...

Comment: What does your `main.php` file look like?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>BLAH</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Bloo bloo blah</h1>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: @Dark Slipstream - See the above comment

Comment: Ok, there is no visible reason for the output issues. Try clearing your cache on chrome and ie and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: nope, still doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

Instead of

```
if ($_GET['mode']) {
```

check if a value for the key `mode` is set before using it:

```
if (isset($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode']) {
```

That's just a precaution in case PHP generates output because of a warning or notice (but must not), which *can* influence the output then.

Next to that you should actually check what the server is returning, not what view source in the browser gives you. Install the [cUrl](http://curl.haxx.se/) commandline tool ([Download](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)) and then run in a shell:

```
curl http://myurl
```

It will output the HTML as your server returns it. This information is actually needed before your problem can be further analyzed.

**Edit:** The cause of your problem is that `main.php` is saved with a BOM. Remove the BOM from the file and you're fine.

**Related:**

- [UTF-8 BOM signature in PHP files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558172/utf-8-bom-signature-in-php-files)
- [Validation error: Byte-Order Mark found in UTF-8 File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986804/validation-error-byte-order-mark-found-in-utf-8-file)

Comment: can you help me with installing curl?

Comment: uploaded result to dropbox: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/36854625/index.html

Comment: All curl downloads, pick one for your operating system: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Comment: @kakre - result (used wget) : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/36854625/index.html

Comment: @comp500: Found your issue (by using curl on your dropbox upload ;) ) - it's the BOM. I edited the question and left you the one and other link to questions that deal with it.