# PHP: Strange character resulting in the first index of array from file() function

Tags: php, text-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I remove ï»¿ from the beginning of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-i-from-the-beginning-of-a-file)

I suspect that this issue has been encountered before, but I can't find anything on it yet. I've tried editing the file various ways, but every time I still get this strange character in the first entry.

So I have a text file (.txt) which includes:

> derek, drw
>
> billy, william
>
> gary, oaktree

Now, I call the file() function and then print like so:

```
<?php 
// read the file into an array called $users
$users = file('C:/private/filetest_02.txt');
?>
<pre>
<?php print_r($users); ?>
</pre>
```

But, then I receive this output:

> Array
>
> (
>
> ```
> [0] => ï»¿ derek, drw
> [1] => billy, william
> [2] => gary, oaktree
> ```
>
> )

Why is this `ï»¿` character being displayed in the first entry of the array? What can I do to alleviate this? Thanks in advance to anyone who can shed some light on this issue.

Comment: Is there any whitespace at the beginning of the `txt` file?

Comment: No, there is none and adding will only result in "(whitespace)ï»¿ derek, drw"

Comment: Seems to be Unicode BOM.

Comment: Is the BOM, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-i-from-the-beginning-of-a-file

Comment: Yes, it looks like BOM as characters in UTF-8.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290849/how-to-remove-multiple-utf-8-bom-sequences-before-doctype for easier solution too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a [UTF-8 byte order marker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding).

You need to modify the file to remove it.

Comment: How would one modify that?

Comment: Use a text editor, such as notepad++ to save the file without a BOM.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6986922/1517648  If you're using a Linux distro then editors such as `gedit` or `kate` might be able to do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like I should start using notepad++. :)