# '2' character with star inside?

Tags: python, character

**Edit: Determined so far: It's not the 2, it's a character before the two, hex value BF, causing the star in the following character (which happens to be 2)**

I'm running an elastic-mapreduce job using python scripts I have written, and I'm getting some weird output in the form of unexpected lines.  I have noticed a pattern, however.  The expected lines all have unexpected '2's in the form of characters with small stars just inside the top curve of the character.  That is, when I open the file in Notepad++ (but not Notepad or Word) I see some twos show up like this (excuse the links, I am unable to embed images at less than 10 rep):

> In text:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaVyb.png
>   Zoomed in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPCrV.png

The weird '2's also show up when I run the python scripts on my own machine (though the unexpected lines do not).  Does anyone know what might be causing this? It might shed some light on the odd extra lines of output I'm getting.  I'm also just genuinely curious.

Also, I thought it might have had to do with encoding/decoding I was doing to parse safe URLs, but when I took out those parts the weird '2's remained, so it wasn't that.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a short snippet of code that generates this? Can you open the file with a binary editor to see what character codes are causing this? It looks related to character encoding - but need more info.

Comment: Using the binary editor I figured out that it's not the 2, it's the character before it, value BF, that's causing the star.  It's actually not in the 2 -- if I delete the 2 the character that takes its place has the star in it.  It's just the previous character throwing a star in it...

As for the code, there really isn't any particular piece of the code that stands out to me as particularly suspect, and pasting the whole code in isn't possible, unfortunately. :(

Comment: What encoding is your output supposed to be in?  0xBF is an inverted question mark (¿) in Latin-1, but can only appear as a trailing part of an encoded character in UTF-8.  If your output is UTF-8, we need to see a few more bytes to be able to figure out what's causing this (e.g. one whole line from INPUT LINE to end of line).

Comment: Here's a full line:

`49 4e 50 55 54 20 4c 49 4e 45 3a 20 20 ef bb bf 32 30 31 33 2d 30 37 2d 32 32 2d 31 34 3a 30 30 20 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 70 6c 61 63 65 68 6f 6c 64 65 72 2e 65 6c 61 73 74 69 63 62 65 61 6e 73 74 61 6c 6b 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 73 65 61 72 63 68 20 36 38 39 20 31 09`

Which equates to:

INPUT LINE:  2013-07-22-14:00 `http://placeholder.elasticbeanstalk.com/search 689 1 `

As for the encoding type, I hadn't given it any thought prior to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `EF BB BF` in there... that's the UTF-8 encoding of the `BOM` mark: byte order mark. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark . I suspect that the star in the letter is your editor's way of signifying "I just got a BOM". See [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6986804/1967396) . It seems to be a well known "thing", and that thread has some suggestions for dealing with it.