# NOtepad and Apache don't detect line breaks I save with Notepad++

Tags: php, apache, xampp, notepad++, notepad

i have a problem with my PHP Code. I wrote something simple:

```
<?php
echo("Hello World");
?>
```

Now using xampp locally it works. But when I upload (with Filezilla) and run it on my webserver (Apache, PHP 5.3.24) I get following error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function phpecho() in /home/www/earthlost/index.php on line 1

I already figured out, that when I save the file with Notepad++, and open it in Notepad, I get following content:

```
<?phpecho("Hello World");?>
```

So obviously, Notepad++ saves some linebreaks, that neither Notepad, nor my online Apache detects as such.

I already made sure, that my Notepad++ saves in "UTF-8 with BOM", but it doesn't solve the problem. So, what should I do?

Comment: Try saving as ASCII instead of UTF.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986804/validation-error-byte-order-mark-found-in-utf-8-file

Comment: If you open `View -> Show Symbol -> Show End of Line` in Notepad++ what characters are you seeing at the end of lines?

Comment: @aust Solution there says "use Convert to UTF-8 without BOM", I already did this

Comment: Your issue is that the editor is stripping out the "\n" from the Windows "\r\n" line break sequence.

Comment: @aust do you you know what I can do? I tried several encodings, but Notepad++ always inserts this 'CR'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++ go to the menu `Edit` > `EOL Conversion` and select `UNIX/OSX Format`.

For some reason your file seems to be opened as a `Macintosh` file (with `CR` carriage returns).

After the change, you will see in the right side of your status bar the correct type of newline: [image]